# Unable to use precomputed distances with Elki

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, elki

I am trying to use precomputed distances with Elki, but for some reason cannot get it working. I have read the instructions here: http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/HowTo/PrecomputedDistances and this question on SO: [ELKI - input distance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677527/elki-input-distance-matrix).

Unfortunately I am still unable to get ELKI working.

This is the command I am running in a bash shell:

```
java -jar  elki.jar -verbose  -dbc.filter FixedDBIDsFilter -dbc.startid 0 -dbc.in elki_dummy_ids -algorithm clustering.kmeans.KMeansLloyd -algorithm.distancefunction external.FileBasedDoubleDistanceFunction -distance.matrix elki_sample_dist_ut.txt -kmeans.k 3
```

And these are the contents of the files in the parameters:

```
$cat elki_dummy_ids
0
1
2


$cat elki_sample_dist_ut.txt
0 0 0.0000
0 1 0.8876
0 2 0.8571
1 1 0.0
1 2 0.9059
2 2 0.0
```

I tried with a lower-triangular distance matrix too:

```
$cat elki_sample_dist_lt.txt
0 0 0.0000
1 0 0.8876
1 1 0.0
2 0 0.8571
2 1 0.9059
2 2 0.0
```

but no luck with that either. 
I keep getting this error (truncated - but let me know if you need the full error msg):

> The following parameters were not processed:
>   [external.FileBasedDoubleDistanceFunction, -distance.matrix,
>   elki_sample_dist_ut.txt] Task is not completely configured:
>
> Wrong value of parameter algorithm.distancefunction. Read:
>   de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.distance.distancefunction.external.FileBasedDoubleDistanceFunction.
>   Expected: Distance function to determine the distance between database
>   objects. Implementing
>   de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.distance.distancefunction.PrimitiveDistanceFunction
>   Known classes (default package
>   de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.distance.distancefunction):

I am using *OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1)* and *Elki 0.6.0*.

Can someone please point out what I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

k-means **cannot** be used with precomputed distances.

Because it computes distances from points to *centroids*, which you do not know before, and thus cannot be precomputed.

Plus, k-means *should* only be used on *numerical* data, with *squared Euclidean distance*. Otherwise it may fail to converge. The *mean* minimizes sum-of-squared deviations, and **does not minimize arbitrary distances**.

You might be looking for PAM, k-medoids, DBSCAN, OPTICS, HAC, ... these algorithms *do* work with other distances, and only need pairwise distances.

Comment: Yes, of course. I was tripped by the error message. I just picked the first algo that came to my mind and tried to run it with a toy dataset just to make sure the external distance file _parses_. The elki website mentions that in one particular version parsing errors were reported as "Wrong value of parameter algorithm.distancefunction" and I assumed, incorrectly, that was what was happening. Trying the DBScan the errors disappear - thanks! (btw I wasn't blaming Elki and I apologize if it seemed like that - its a great piece of s/w!)

Comment: "blame" probably was a too strong word. It's DBSCAN btw - all uppercase - it's an acronym.